# Other websockets does not work when a websocket is pending

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I use Django Channels and I have multiple websocket addresses. When I connect to a websocket, it gets and computes somethings from database and this process may take 10 seconds. But during this 10 seconds all of my websockets does not respond to any user and it yields a 502 Bad Gateway to every user.

It seems that all of my websockets are running by a single agent, and when it is pending, all other websockets does not respond anymore, until the agent becomes free. My code is some like the following code.

How can I solve this problem?

```
class SymbolConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.symbol_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["symbol_name"]
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.symbol_name, self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

        self.send(time_consuming_function_1(self.symbol_name))
        self.send(time_consuming_function_2(self.symbol_name))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.symbol_name, self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        pass
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your consumer with the issue to your question? Is your consumer sync or async?

Comment: @IainShelvington Code is added.